# How can I disable remote wipe, in a way that can't be remotely re-enabled?

Tags: android-device-manager, device-administrator, remote-wipe

I don't want my Android phone to be remotely wipeable. I have this setting disabled on my phone, and the device administrator for Find My Device is disabled. However, https://android.com/find has an "Enable lock and erase" button that will remotely change these settings back, which seems to defeat the purpose of having them in the first place. How can I actually turn these off in a way that can't be remotely turned back on?

Comment: Have you tested that Find My Device can reenable wiping remotely or is it just a guess?

Comment: @Robert I've previously tested that it actually does change the settings I mentioned, but I haven't tried actually doing the wipe.